# "a wooden object covered in magically turning cogs and wheels" meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Luna was not there: the thing that was making such a racket was **a wooden object covered in magically turning cogs and wheels**. It looked like the bizarre offspring of a workbench and a set of old shelves, but after a moment Harry deduced that it was an old-fashioned printing press due to the fact that it was churning out *Quibblers*.
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I don't understand "a wooden object covered in magically turning cogs and wheels", especially the phrase "covered in".

I looked up "[cover in](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cover+in)". It seems to me that this sense might fit for my context:

> 3. To become coated in something. In this usage, "cover" is often used in the past tense without a noun or pronoun between "cover" and "in."
>
> *After hours of gardening, Eva was covered in dirt.*
>
> *I was quickly covered in blood after the ball hit me in the face.*

Have I gotten it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,  you can use "covered in" not only with liquids like blood or mud, but it can also when something has many things on it, so the object is hidden.

> The floor was covered in socks.
>
> His face was covered in spots.

In this example there is an old fashioned print press, but the actual printing plates are hidden behind lots of cogs and machinery that is magically operating the press to produce a magazine.